# Why am I unable to get any organization repositories from gatsby-source-github-api?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, github-api, gatsby-plugin

Wanting to build a metrics on private and public repo issues and pull requests I found the Gatsby plugin [`gatsby-source-github-api`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-github-api/).

Following the [PAT docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) I created a PAT token for my Github username.

In my *gatsby-config.js* I added:

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

const { githubApiQuery } = require('./src/utils/github-api')

{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-github-api`,
  options: {
    // token: required by the GitHub API
    token: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN,

    // GraphQLquery: defaults to a search query
    graphQLQuery: githubApiQuery,

    // variables: defaults to variables needed for a search query
    variables: {
      github_login: process.env.GITHUB_LOGIN,
      repo_count: 100,
    },
  },
},
```

*.env.development*:

```
GITHUB_TOKEN=github-long-token-from-pat
GITHUB_LOGIN=org-name
```

Testing my query I went to [Github's GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer) and built:

```
query($github_login: String!, $repo_count: Int!){
  viewer {
    organization(login: $github_login) {
      login
      id
      location
      name
      url
      repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy:PRIVATE) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          openGraphImageUrl
          createdAt
          stargazerCount
          url
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Query variables:

```
{"github_login": "org-name", "repo_count": 100}
```

Built an API file, *github-api.js*:

```
exports.githubApiQuery = `
query($github_login: String!, $repo_count: Int!){
  viewer {
    organization(login: $github_login) {
      login
      id
      location
      name
      url
      repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy:PRIVATE) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          openGraphImageUrl
          createdAt
          stargazerCount
          url
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Restarted my project with `npm start` and navigated to my URL, http://localhost:8000/___graphql, and in GraphiQL tried to build a query with the data but `data` is not present:

[image: allGithubData]

Seeing if this had been asked I read through:

- [error "gatsby-source-github-api" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle: token is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65876158/error-gatsby-source-github-api-threw-an-error-while-running-the-sourcenodes-li)
- [Error when deploying the gatsby app with gatsby-source-buttercms on Zeit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58431689/error-when-deploying-the-gatsby-app-with-gatsby-source-buttercms-on-zeit)
- [Populating Github GraphQL in React (Gatsby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362960/populating-github-graphql-in-react-gatsby)
- [Graphql query data from github api in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64126194/graphql-query-data-from-github-api-in-gatsby)
- [netlify deployment build is failing for gatsby-contentful site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150942/netlify-deployment-build-is-failing-for-gatsby-contentful-site)

### Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.4",
  "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
  "formik": "^2.2.9",
  "gatsby": "^4.10.3",
  "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^4.10.2",
  "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^4.10.1",
  "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^4.10.0",
  "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.11.1",
  "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.10.2",
  "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^5.10.2",
  "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.10.0",
  "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.7.0",
  "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.11.1",
  "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.10.2",
  "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^5.10.0",
  "gatsby-remark-images": "^6.10.2",
  "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^6.10.0",
  "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^5.10.0",
  "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^5.10.0",
  "gatsby-source-contentful": "^7.9.1",
  "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.11.1",
  "gatsby-source-github-api": "^1.0.0",
  "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^5.10.2",
  "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.11.0",
  "prismjs": "^1.27.0",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
  "react-hot-toast": "^2.2.0",
  "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
  "typeface-merriweather": "0.0.72",
  "typeface-montserrat": "0.0.75"
},
```

Why am I unable to get any `data` from an org with the `gatsby-source-github-api` plugin or is there a particular way I get all my repository information? The above query in Github's GraphQL API works and I can get all my private repos but how can I do this in Gatsby?

### Edit

Token Permissions under `Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens`:

Select scopes I've given full `repo` permissions.

Further reading I found [Cant get gatsby-source-github-api to load properly](https://github.com/ldd/gatsby-source-github-api/issues/23) which had a comment that suggested:

change query with addition of `isFork: false`:

```
exports.githubApiQuery = `
query($github_login: String!, $repo_count: Int!){
  viewer {
    organization(login: $github_login) {
      login
      id
      location
      name
      url
      repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy: PRIVATE, isFork: false) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          openGraphImageUrl
          createdAt
          stargazerCount
          url
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

changed in config with the addition of `url`:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-github-api`,
  options: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',

    // token: required by the GitHub API
    token: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN,

    // GraphQLquery: defaults to a search query
    graphQLQuery: githubApiQuery,

    // variables: defaults to variables needed for a search query
    variables: {
      github_login: process.env.GITHUB_LOGIN,
      repo_count: 100,
    },
  },
},
```

### Edit 2

Trying different approaches I've tried:

**query**

```
query ($github_org: String!, $github_login: String!, $repo_count: Int!) {
  user(login: $github_login) {
    organization(login: $github_org) {
      login
      id
      location
      name
      url
      repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy: PRIVATE, isFork: false) {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          openGraphImageUrl
          createdAt
          stargazerCount
          url
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**variables**

```
{"github_login":"github-username","github_org": "github-org", "repo_count": 100}
```

added to config:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-github-api`,
  options: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',

    // token: required by the GitHub API
    token: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN,

    // GraphQLquery: defaults to a search query
    graphQLQuery: githubApiQuery,

    // variables: defaults to variables needed for a search query
    variables: {
      github_login: process.env.GITHUB_LOGIN,
      github_org: process.env.GITHUB_ORG,
      repo_count: 100,
    },
  },
}
```

added to api file:

```
exports.githubApiQuery = `
query($github_login: String!, $github_org: String!, $repo_count: Int!){
  user(login: $github_login) {
  organization(login: $github_org) {
    login
    id
    location
    name
    url
    repositories(first: $repo_count, privacy: PRIVATE, isFork: false) {
      nodes {
        id
        name
        openGraphImageUrl
        createdAt
        stargazerCount
        url
        description
      }
    }
  }
  }
`
```

Above approach still returns a result in Github's Explorer but when I try with GraphiQL I'm not able to get anything.

Comment: What permissions did you give to the token?

Comment: @FerranBuireu made an edit with additional attempts. Also, just for testing I edited the PAT with everything checked, re-generated and rebooted with the same result in a new browser window of the `__graphql`.